# WebSocket4Net issue with multiple frames

Tags: websocket, frames, websocket4net

I have a WebSocket Server that I can hit from a browser and get valid messages that parse JSON correctly.  These messages are large, about 9K, and when looking at Google Chome Developer Tools I can see that its coming in multiple frames.

Now, I've been trying to hit the same service from a console application using WebSocket4Net.  The smaller messages come across fine, but my larger messages are getting messed up.  Basically, at the point where the Chrome Developer Tools are showing me where the initial frame ends, I'm getting the start of the next actual message, not the continuation frame.

I'm seeing some funny characters when looking at the HEX, at the point of the message truncation...seeing (HEX)  80 7e 06 15  .... or something close, but it always begins with '80 7e'.

I've increased the ReceiveBufferSize to 12,000, but that doesn't seem to help.

Anybody else ever see this?
Thanks.

Comment: I think you should increase the SendBufferSize in the client if available

Comment: There is no such setting in WebSocket4Net.  Found that setting in Alchemy WebSockets, but never got that to connect correctly.

Comment: So I decided to try this out using System.Net.WebSockets in 4.5 on a Windows 8 VM that I created for this purpose. The ClientWebSocket class works great with the only pain being that you have to handle the multiple frames yourself by interogating the EndOfMessage variable and if no, keep appending the incoming segments. I'm calling the same service as the OP, and now its working. So the problem must lie in the WebSocket4Net pluggin. –

Comment: Anybody ever see this??????

Comment: I think so. But  it would be better if you write it as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to get some help on the CodePlex site.  If you are having any issues like I was, check this posting out (https://websocket4net.codeplex.com/workitem/35).

Have a great day!